# Оператор и пустые строки

Tags: операторы, php

передаю `ajaxom` в `php`, но не срабатывает я так понимаю может там пробелы и поля не совсем пусты?

```
if (empty($email) && empty($email2) && empty($email3)) {
 echo $error;
 exit();
 }
```

Comment: он обрабатывает если хоть одно из этих полей заполнено а нужно что бы все проверял

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($email=="" || $email2=="" || $email3=="") { echo $error; exit(); }
```

Comment: Вместо "=", по всей видимости, должно быть "==" или "===". Да и ошибку можно прямо в exit передать. Думаю, echo тут необязательно.

    exit($error);

Comment: @VenZell, ну конечно! ))) Ох, уж этот Бейсик!

Comment: надо изменить!

Answer (score 0):

хмм... попробуйте в php в самом начале написать:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) { $_POST[$key] = trim($val); }
```